# How to add custom choice to django CharField, where it takes argument as choices

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add custom choices in my Coustom List which is listed in "constanst.py" file

```
constants.py

DAYS_CHOICE = [
('Monday - Friday', 'monday - friday'),
('Monday - Saturday', 'monday - saturday'), 
('Flexible', 'flexible'),]

models.py

class JobPost(Timestampable, SoftDeletes):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, editable=False, default = uuid.uuid4)
creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[CustomLengthValidator(min_length=2, max_length=255, field_name='title')]) 
schedule_days = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=DAYS_CHOICE)
```

and i am importing that in the field,
now the issue is when user enters the choice which is not in by default list it has to accept has add to the end of the default list..

Comment: Could you rephrase your question ? Describe what you want, what you get, what you think you should get, and why do think this is a problem for example.

Comment: If you want dynamic choices for scheduled days. You've got to make another model for choices for scheduled_days field and create a custom method for  **JobPost** model to pull all the choices for schedule_days field from the other model.